# Adding one to cell in second sheet via button click

Tags: button, excel, vba

I'm very new to anything beyond very basic Excel functionality.  I am trying to build a simple spreadsheet to help keep stats for a sporting event.  I want to have buttons on which I can click which then add one (numerical value) to a corresponding cell in a second sheet.  I figured out that this code will do what I want for a single button on the first sheet and a single cell on the second sheet:

```
Sub Player_Pass()
Sheets("Sheets").Range("C4").Value = Sheets("Stats").Range("C4").Value + 1
End Sub
```

But I have about 100 buttons and it seems that creating a separate module for each button with a different name and different parameters is not the most elegant solution.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This may be what you intend, but no matter how many times you press that button, `Sheets("Sheets").Range("C4").Value` will always be only one more than `Sheets("Stats").Range("C4").Value + 1`, unless you've incremented the `Stats` range somewhere else.

Comment: Also, I always recommend against the "button-per-row" approach. I find it hard to mantain. You could instead maybe use a [WorkSheet_DoubleClick](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/event.htm#ws_bdc) event for something simple like this. But that's just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign all the buttons to a common macro and then use `Application.Caller` to determine what action to take

```
Sub ButtonClicked()
    Dim ac

    ac = Application.Caller
    Debug.Print ac, ActiveSheet.Shapes(ac).TopLeftCell.Address()
    'do some action according to which button was clicked...

End Sub
```

Comment: Or use hyperlinks (which just point back to the cell they're in) and capture the sheet–FollowHyperlink event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo exitSub
    With Target
    If .Column = 1 Then
    If .Row < 4 Then Exit Sub
    Sheets("Stats").Range("C" & .Row).Value = Sheets("Stats").Range("C" & .Row).Value + 1
    .Offset(0, 3).value = Sheets("Stats").Range("C" & .Row).Value
    .Offset(0, 1).Select
    End If
    End With
exitSub:
End Sub
```

Put this in your **"Sheets"** worksheet

this will turn the 1st column cells greater than row 3 into a button that increments stat

just modify the column and row number to position the virtual button